# Add feature names to decision tree Julia

Tags: julia

Following from the example provided at [Julia's Decision Tree Github](https://github.com/JuliaAI/DecisionTree.jl)

I want to print_tree with the feature names displayed, so instead of "feature 1" --> "sepal Lenght"

```
using DecisionTree

features, labels = load_data("iris")    # also see "adult" and "digits" datasets
features = float.(features)
labels   = string.(labels)
 # subsitute these column names for "feature 1/2/3/4" 
feauture_names = ["sepal length"," sepal width", "petal length", "petal width"]
# train depth-truncated classifier
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
fit!(model, features, labels)
# pretty print of the tree, to a depth of 5 nodes (optional)
print_tree(model, 5) #print here using feature_names
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
Feature 3, Threshold 2.45
L-> Iris-setosa : 50/50
R-> Feature 4, Threshold 1.75
    L-> Iris-versicolor : 49/54
    R-> Iris-virginica : 45/46
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
"petal width", Threshold 2.45
L-> Iris-setosa : 50/50
R-> "petal width", Threshold 1.75
    L-> Iris-versicolor : 49/54
    R-> Iris-virginica : 45/46
```

Comment: Use `print_tree(model, 5; feature_names=feauture_names)`. Note the spelling mistake in variable name in both OP, and replicated here (without spelling mistake `print_tree(model, 5; feature_names)` is enough)